# If you mute a player, can he still read you in the chat?

Tags: league-of-legends

**After you've muted a player, can he still read you in the chat (and all-chat) ?**

Comment: Don't understand the downvotes. It's in nowhere stated that players YOU muted are still able to receive your input, as as such it IS a good question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes they can still see your messages you type. You muted them, but unless they mute you, they can see your messages. I know this from duo queueing with people.

Answer (score 3):

Has we can see [here](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2386524) yes, they can still read your messages, because **YOU** muted him, **HE** didn't, you don't see the messages of someone you muted but they are able to see yours, also, if you for some reason mute a friend and don't remove the mute he will automatically be removed from your friend list (At least used to work like this, lost some flaming *friends* like this)